# Huge Storage for Weblogic JMS Server

Tags: java, oracle11g, jms, bigdata, weblogic11g

In my weblogic server (4 nodes) I defined a migratable JMS Server with (Oracle) Database Storage. Here I receive 1000 messages per second. Every message is an XML message of about 1kB.

I might have the need to stop the java MDB for 1 day and store several GB of data (due to maintenance).

**how can I (with little overhead) save these messages compressed in order to reduce the space?**

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities, but generally speaking the main idea is to compress data:

1. compress message: [suggested by oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/perform/jmstuning.html#wp1149361)
2. compress TableSpace; not suggetsed by Oracle

then let me suggest the first solution; then, you can enable weblogic compression or your custom compression on producer and consumer.

### Weblogic compression

> Navigate to JMS Connection Factory -> Click the Configuration >
>   Default Delivery tab. On the Default Delivery page -> Default
>   Compression Threshold

### Custom GZIP Compression

- compress xml message before sending
- uncompress when you receive

for instance I use the following code on MDB to extract text if the producer compressed message or not;

```
   protected String getText(Message message) throws JMSException, IOException {
    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        return ((TextMessage) message).getText();
    } else if (message instanceof BytesMessage) {
        byte zipped[] = new byte[(int) ((BytesMessage) message)
                .getBodyLength()];
        ((BytesMessage) message).readBytes(zipped);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(zipped);
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        GZIPInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null)
                    in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("getText: ", e);
            }
            try {
                if (bais != null)
                    bais.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("getText: ", e);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        throw new JMSException("Unrecognized message type "
                + message.getClass());
    }
}
```

### Custom EXI Compression

Recently I evalued the [Efficient XML Interchange (EXI) Format 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/exi/).
Here the indicators:

- original message: 8903B
- gzipped message: 1212B
- exi schemaless: 903B
- exi with schema: 856B

but the only java open source implementation is the [exi proxessor](http://exificient.sourceforge.net/?id=ext-tools) proposed by siemens